# Unknown backups on main hard drive

Tags: macbook-pro, time-capsule, storage

On my MacBook's 'About This Mac' pane there is a section that is taking up a lot of storage it is titled 'Backups'.
Now I do use a Time Capsule but I don't know why it would be labeled under my MacBook's hard drive.
Can anyone help me identify and solve this problem?
Here is a screenshot of what I see.
[image: About This Mac Pane]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those might be [Local Backups Feature of Time Machine](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202301).

> Local snapshots complement regular Time Machine backups that are stored on your external disk or Time Capsule by creating a local backup on your startup disk when your normal backup drive is not available. This provides you with a "safety net" for times when you might be away from your external backup disk or Time Capsule but accidentally delete a file. When your normal backup is available again, Time Machine copies the local snapshot contents from your startup disk to your normal backup drive.

Read the link above for detailed explanation.

Comment: Now I don't have to erase my whole hard drive and potentially cause myself problems.

Comment: http://wiki.summercode.com/how_to_disable_mobile_backups_on_lion if you need to disable it

Comment: @iskra feel free to reward the OP with points if the question was clear and detailed and you answered it. Just common curtsey.